# Using Profiles to allow member to view/edit own details only

Tags: wordpress, api, profile

I am trying to work out how to use a profile to allow a registered member of an organisation/registered user of a Wordpress site, to access/view their own information and edit certain fields.

In theory this appears to be possible, but even though I've used profiles quite a lot over the years, I can't work out how to do this.

Ideally the user would login to the front end of the website (not the backend/dashboard), view their own membership details, view/edit their personal contact details, but not have access to any other details.

The part I don't understand is how the User Contact ID would be populated to the profile in such a way as that contact's information was automatically selected after login.

Or would this all be done more easily using the CiviCRM API and a bit of programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're asking for:

Create a new profile. Call it something friendly for the user like "My Contact Details". Tick it as a "Standalone Form or Directory"
Fill it with the fields you want the user to edit.

Pick the page you want them to be accessible and edit it. Use the CiviCRM button to pick the profile or enter in the shortcode yourself.

It should similar to,

```
[civicrm component="profile" gid="123" mode="edit" hijack="0"]
```

When a user is logged in, this will contain the fields you selected to be edited by the user.

Edit: while the anonymous visitor will not see the profile fields until he/she is logged in,  I guess it'd be good practice to make the wp page *private* to avoid any slips and keep the design fluid  - or use a plugin to limit the page to logged in users.

Comment: This does the trick. For some reason the documentation just doesn't really seem to explain how simple this is to do.